# Live search is not initialized in bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, bootstrap-select

I use React.js and would like to use [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) with [live search](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search) feature, but bootstrap-select is initialized without live-search feauture.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/27522/)

```
var SelectPicker = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      value: optionItems[0]
    }
  },

  _onChange: function(){
    console.log('change');
  },

  render: function() {

  var options = this.props.items.map((object, i) =>
    <option key={i} value={object}>
    {object}
    </option>
  );

    return (
      <div className="selectWrapper">
      <label htmlFor={"selectNum"}>Number</label>
      <select id={"selectNum"}
      ref="selectPicker"
      className="form-control selectPicker"
      data-live-search="true"
      onChange={this._onChange}
      value={this.state.value}>
      {options}
      </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var optionItems = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <SelectPicker items={optionItems} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

If I initialize select-picker [without react](https://jsfiddle.net/bhot616k/11/) it works ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need initialize `selectpicker`, you can do it in `componentDidMount` like this

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  $(this.refs.selectPicker).selectpicker({
    liveSearch: true
  });
},
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/27527/)